# Custom .net TCP server

Tags: c#, azure, tcp, tcplistener

Created .net custom tcp server and client using tcplistener. Taks is simple to exchange the data. I have Windows server, on which I am able to communicate. Within network also I am able to communicate. When I deploy this same on our web server, public IP is not accepting connections. At client side it throws time out error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond .....

Trace route shows request is going there till server and at the end its not showing time out. Server is VM on azure.

Comment: Code is always helpful. Though, it sounds like a firewall issue on your VM. Make sure whatever port you're trying to use isn't blocked.

Comment: did you add endpoints to the VM?

Comment: Here is code, I have added the Endpoint to VM, opened the port in firewall. .. still not able to reach the machine. .. Code is simple and copied from MSDN , I even tried chaning many ports.....

     IPAddress[] addrs = Dns.GetHostEntry(name).AddressList;

                listener = new TcpListener(2055);
                listener.Start();

Answer (score 0):

Add the endpoint to the Azure configuration:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It was firewall issue. It is resolved but I am clueless about the problem. Firewall ports opened earlier did not worked. so I stopped firewall and I found its working. later on I started and firewall it again worked. strange....fire wall is not updated it seems.

Thanks.
Kishor